# Poisson model in R Jags - Error in node NbBones[4] Node inconsistent with parents

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I have a dataframe such as ;

```
Orders  Time  NbBones
1      12    21
1      34    43
2      32    0
3      21    0
2      10    0
```

And the jags poisson model:

```
Poisson_model<-"
model 
{
  for(i in 1 : N) 
  {
    NbBones[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    lambda[i] <-  alpha + Coeforder[Orders[i]]  + Coeftime * Time[i] 
  }
  Coeforder[1] <- 0
  Coeforder[2] ~ dnorm(0,1)
  Coeforder[3] ~ dnorm(0,1) 
  Coeftime ~ dnorm(0,1) 
  alpha ~ dexp(1)  
}
"

data4jags <- list(Time = data$Time, NbBones = data$NbBones, Orders=data$Orders, N=length(data$Orders))


m1 <- jags.model(textConnection(Poisson_model), data = data4jags, n.chains = 3)
```

But when I run the code in R I get the following error message :

```
Error in jags.model(textConnection(Model1), data = data4jags, n.chains = 3) : 
  Error in node NbBones[4]
Node inconsistent with parents
```

Does someone understand where is the issue in the code ? Thanks a lot for your time

---

For Ben Bolker

You mean to code like that ?

```
model1<-"
model 
{
  for(i in 1 : N) 
  {
    NbEVES_branche[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    partial[i] <- alpha + Coeftime * Time[i]
    if (Orders[i]>1) {
    lambda[i] <-  partial[i] + Coeforder[Orders[i-1]]
}
Coeforder[1] ~ dnorm(0,1)
Coeforder[2] ~ dnorm(0,1) 
Coeftime ~ dnorm(0,1) 
alpha ~ dexp(1)  

  }
  "
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things jump out at me. (1) your model allows negative values for the mean of a Poisson (although I expect that would give you a different error); (2) I'd be surprised if you were allowed to use an array (`Coeforder`) where the first element is a logical node (0) while the others are stochastic nodes. This eventually worked for me:

```r
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
Orders  Time  NbBones
1      12    21
1      34    43
2      32    0
3      21    0
2      10    0
")


ddj <- c(as.list(dd), N=nrow(dd))

model1<-"model {
  for(i in 1 : N) {
    NbBones[i] ~ dpois(lambda[i])
    partial[i] <- alpha + Coeftime * Time[i]
    lambda[i] <- ifelse(Orders[i] > 1,
         partial[i] + Coeforder[max(1,Orders[i]-1)],
         partial[i])
    }
    Coeforder[1] ~ dnorm(0,1)
    Coeforder[2] ~ dnorm(0,1) 
    Coeftime ~ dnorm(0,1)
    alpha ~ dexp(1)
}"

writeLines(model1, "tmp.jags")
library(rjags)
m1 <- jags.model("tmp.jags", ddj, n.chains = 3)
```

Note that JAGS doesn't have an `if/else` statement. The `max(1,...)` clause is necessary because the `ifelse()` statement always evaluates both of its potential outputs, even if they're not going to get used (so we have to be careful to avoid referring to `Coeforder[0]`).

More compactly, you could set up a model matrix `X` outside of JAGS and use a structure like `lambda[i] <- exp(inprod(X[i,], beta))` where `beta` is your full coefficient vector (this mimics the structure of a standard Poisson GLM, including a log link/exponential inverse-link component)

Comment: Hi Ben, thank for your quick answer, I edited my code to show you what I tried with your code, but I still get the same issue, any idea how where is the issue ?